# Time to maturity (TTM) shifted for day conversion using RQuantlib in R

Tags: r, quantlib

I'm using `RQuantlib` package in R to calculate the implied volatility. As a input to the function `EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility` I use TTM days divided by 365. But if I use the output implied volatility to calculate the option price back using hand crafted Black Scholes function, I end with a different values.

I found the cause to be in the `europeanOptionImpliedVolatilityEngine`, which converts the input fractional year by using the conversion

```
int(maturity*360 + 0.5);
```

Source: [RQuantlib github](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/blob/master/src/implieds.cpp#L39)

So this ends up shifting the TTM values passed on to the C code function with difference of 1 day in some cases, about 70% of the data got date shifted in my case.

```
x=OptGreeks$TTM/365
y=floor(x*360+0.5)
z=OptGreeks$TTM - y
table(z)
```

Output

```
z
   0    1 
2636 4910
```

Any idea why this is being done and any measure the get the correct days (TTM) passed instead of this anomaly? Hope someone listens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should probably be extended so that one can choose a day-count convention, and that's the way to go if you're familiar with C++ and can patch and recompile RQuantLib.

In the meantime, I'm afraid that the way to work around the problem is for you to use days/360, too.  This means you'll also have to adjust your input rates and the output volatility; the relations you want to satisfy are r<sub>360</sub> t<sub>360</sub> = r<sub>365</sub> t<sub>365</sub> (from which you'll get the r<sub>360</sub> to pass as input, given your r<sub>365</sub>) and sigma<sup>2</sup><sub>360</sub> t<sub>360</sub> = sigma<sup>2</sup><sub>365</sub> t<sub>365</sub> (from which you'll get sigma<sub>365</sub> given the returned sigma<sub>360</sub>).

Comment: Nice answer. I said something similar (though less refined) in an issue ticket I got on this, presumably from the OP here.

Comment: @LuigiBallabio Tried recompiling after changing the C function. It failed, probably needs boost/quantlib cpp lib, but my paths are in a mess and it'll take a lit of work. So for the time I'm going with your idea.   @ DirkEddelbuettel yeah I had opened that issue.